# HTML indentation doesn't work

Tags: html, eclipse, indentation

I use Eclipse WTP 3.3

I've removed all the elements from 
Window > preferences > Web > HTML files > Editor > inline Elements 
And yet when I press the combination ctrl + shift + F while editing HTML sources, it simply left-aligns everything. (I open the files for editing by right clicking on them in the project explorer and choosing Open With > HTML Editor)

Comment: Can you show an example? Does it work better in a more recent release (we're days from 3.7.0)?

Comment: @nitind It still doesn't work, I've switched to Aptana, as it suits my needs better.